# Use a request body with requestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, requestjs

I am using [requestjs](https://github.com/request/request) to send a request to https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/search.do.

The request should look like this:

[image: Response I need to write in JavaScript]

How can I add a request body?

My attempt:

```js
function callback(error, response, body) {
 if (error) return error;

 // write the body to an external file
 fs.writeFileSync('body.html', body);

 return body;
}

function writeFile(url = 'https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/search.do') {
 const headers = {
    // headers, as you can see in the picture. I am sure my headers a correct.
    
  // this is probably NOT the right place for using a request body, right? At least it does not work ...
  qs:
   'suchTyp=n&registerArt=&registerNummer=&registergericht=R3102&schlagwoerter=&schlagwortOptionen=2&ergebnisseProSeite=100&btnSuche=Find'
 };

 const options = {
  url, // https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/search.do
  headers
 };

 return request(options, callback);
}
writeFile().then(() => {
 console.log('finished');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to the `options` argument instead of headers, and it should be as a JSON object like this:

```
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', form: {key:'value'}}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ })
```

Take a look here: https://github.com/request/request#forms

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
data= {
key1:value1,
key2:value2,
...
...
}  

request.post({url:' https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/search.do',form: data},
function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error('request failed:', err);
          }
          console.log('Request successful!  Server responded with:', body);
);
```